# Which part of speech has the fewest words?

Tags: parts-of-speech

Every word is a particular part of speech.  Which part of speech has the fewest words?

Comment: There are many nouns and verbs and adjectives and adverbs.  **Conjunctions,** not so many.

Comment: If you consider the article a separate part of speech, it has the fewest. Otherwise I'd probably go with conjunction, preposition, or maybe pronoun.

Comment: In English, probly pronoun -- unless you count article, as Matt points out. Of course every language has their own set of parts of speech, with their own peculiarities; there are languages where adjective would be the the smallest class, for instance.

Comment: In an article from, I believe, Sussex University and [available from here](https://www.scribd.com/doc/45978806/Essay-Parts-of-Speech) is found: In some cases, we find that a single word exhibits unique behaviour, behaviour shared by no other word in the language. Such a word is occasionally called a syncategorematic item, a very fancy word meaning ‘belonging to a category of which it is the only member’. The best known such item in English is the negative _not_, which behaves differently from every other word in the language. Traditional grammarians, as usual with difficult words, ...

Comment: called the word an “adverb”, but in fact there is not a single property that _not_ shares with the adverbs – unlike, for example, _never_, which really is an adverb.

Other such unique words are the polite _please_ (as in Please pass the salt) (a Politeness Marker, like Thank you), the infinitival _to_ (as in I want to go home), the existential _there_ (as in There’s a wasp on your back), delexical it (it’s raining) ... The informal English of younger speakers presents a striking example, the discourse particle _like_, as in I was like, get away from me. Oh, you still believe in 'the Eight'?

Comment: Oh, and I disagree with 'every word is a particular part of speech'. 'Galore' as in 'There were sideshows galore' is both quantifying (many) and adjectival ('gay'; you wouldn't say 'There were corpses galore'). With 'His slowly carving the piece of wood was mesmeric in its effect', the -ing form is somewhere along the noun (used with 'his') - verb (used with 'slowly') continuum.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Is *not* not an adverb? It does *seem* to have an awful lot in common with *never*. For example it occurs in exactly the same position in the sentence: *I am not/never late*, *I have not/never lied to you* etc etc.

Comment: Sometimes – in fact often. But 'never' in 'Never have I seen such bloodlust' isn't echoed. 'Never' adds a time reference that 'not' doesn't; its function is purely to negate. In fact, the functions of 'never' in 'John never cycles' and 'slowly' say in 'Doesn't John cycle slowly' are very different. They both 'attach to' the verb cycle/s, but only one says something further about the cycling process. The other references the 'context', rather like a determiner with a noun.

Comment: I put my money on the vocative particle, of which there is exactly one.

Comment: @RegDwigнt What's the vocative particle?

Comment: [O @Araucaria!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocative_case#English)

Answer (score 3):

Going by the lists at English Grammar Revolution, there are slightly fewer [Conjunctions](http://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/list-of-conjunctions.html) than [Pronouns](http://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/list-of-pronouns.html) in English.  Both manage at least three dozen, though some are phrases rather than individual words.

Next up would be [Interjections](http://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/list-of-interjections.html), but this is a looser category, open to creative expression.  Gadzooks!

Answer (score 3):

Some grammarians would argue that certain elements are *syncategorematic* meaning they are effectively their own part of speech. In other words there are no other words like them. Contenders for this category might be the word *there* in existential constructions such as:

- There's an elephant over there.

... or the infinitival marker *to*, as in *to perambulate*.

However, many grammars include these words in other parts of speech. For example, in the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, they consider *there* to be a Pronoun, and infinitival *to* to be a Subordinator.

Of course, how many parts of speech there are in a category also depends on how many categories are recognized by  that particular grammar. For example, in some grammars Pronouns are their own part of speech, in others they are a subcategory of the Noun class. Generally, word categories that are considered to be ‘lexical’, ( - in other words Nouns, Verbs, Adjectives and Adverbs), are generally larger than the grammatical ones (prepositions, determiners and so forth). Probably the smallest part of speech category posited by a well-established, and academically recognized grammar would be the Subordinator category in the internationally renowned *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Huddleston & Pullum 2002).

CaGEL reassigned a large number of what older traditional grammars used to call Subordinating Conjunctions to the Preposition class. This left a very small number of true Subordinators. In fact there are only six! In case you're interested in which words are included in the class, they are:

- *that*, *for*, *whether*, infinitival-*to*, interrogative-*if* and *how*.

Edit note: I originally wrote *why* for *how* here. Sorry!